# Notification links to wrong StackExchange site

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

> **Moderator Note**: This is already reported on the main StackExchange meta site: [Positive reputation notification for edit approvals uses relative URL, which causes the link to go to the wrong place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391952/positive-reputation-notification-for-edit-approvals-uses-relative-url-which-cau)
>
> You will have better luck tracking that topic/item than tracking here on Ask Ubuntu, as this is a network-wide issue.

---

I have a notification that seems to link to the current StackExchange website I'm on. Here is a screenshot of it linking to AskUbuntu:

[image: Screenshot showing me hovering the cursor over a notification with the site icon of crypto stackexchange, but the link goes to askubuntu]

Now that I'm on `meta.askubuntu.com`, it links to that site instead. What is should link to is `crypto.stackexchange.com`. When clicking the notification, it of course tries to find this question ID on the current site and happens to come up with a 'this question was deleted' and confused the heck out of me for a while.

Not sure where to best report this, sorry if this is not the best spot I just happen to know of the meta post mechanism where you can tag posts with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Already reported on the main SE site here: [Positive reputation notification for edit approvals uses relative URL, which causes the link to go to the wrong place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391952/positive-reputation-notification-for-edit-approvals-uses-relative-url-which-cau)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Answer from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392827/) by [kristinalustig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344828/kristinalustig) (Staff)

> Thanks for reporting! I fixed this issue - it was due to a refactoring error in a switch statement determining how we were creating the URL for the Achievements tab. Those dang fall-throughs... Anyway, it's no longer a relative URL so this should work just fine - please let me know if you're still seeing any issues.